# Agregar accion al controlador e invocar con link_to en la vista:--> ERROR Completed 400 Bad Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, views

En la aplicación clásica ***blog article***…

Quiero agregar una acción en el controlador ***article*** llamada ***ajustar*** llamándola con el método ***post***, básicamente actualizo la columna ***text*** del método ***article*** agregándole solo un asteristo (*) cada vez que se ajusta, pero me arroja el siguiente error:

```
Started POST "/ajustar/5" for ::1 at 2017-06-30 13:03:51 -0400
Processing by ArticlesController#ajustar as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"rTCc5efVQSm5GG1b47uPH7U+xJq9Vh+N9mUvKpn5WDLf0zqBNiwcbOjvkiyIH8
Ccph6rYh0pH/09hGbq9bZq5Q==", "id"=>"5"}
  Article Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [[
"id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 400 Bad Request in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)



ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: article):

app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:59:in `article_params'
app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:37:in `ajustar'
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatc
h/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatc
h/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch
/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (8.0ms)
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatc
h/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch
/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (6.0ms)
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatc
h/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch
/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch
/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (2516.1ms)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fragmentos del código:

**Vista**

D:\Sites\article-ajustar\app\views\articles\index.html.erb

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Titulo</th>
    <th>Articulo</th>
    <th colspan="7"></th>
  </tr>

  <% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= article.title %></td>
      <td><%= article.text %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Mostrar', article_path(article) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Actualizar', edit_article_path(article) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Ajustar', ajustar_path(article), method: :post %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Borrar', article_path(article),
              method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Esta seguro?' } %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

**Controlador**

D:\Sites\article-ajustar\app\controllers\ articles_controller.rb

```
    def ajustar
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
        @article.text = '*' + @article.text
        @article.update(article_params)
    end
...
    private
        def article_params
            params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
        end
```

**Ruta**

D:\Sites\article-ajustar\config\routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
...
  post  '/ajustar/:id' => 'articles#ajustar', as: 'ajustar'
...
end
```

Anexo en github todo el codigo de la aplicacion

https://github.com/rrg1459/article-ajustar.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si solo vas a agregar un asterisco a un campo, no necesitas acceder a `article_params`, ya que eso implica que vas a requerir parámetros que no estás enviando en tu `POST`. Tu código debería ser como:

```
def ajustar
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.update(text: "*#{@article.text}")
end
```

Comment: Excelente hermano, justo lo que necesitaba!